# FontAwesome half animation?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm currently trying to use their animations to make a transition animation. For example, if I press a button, I want it to play the first half of the shake animation with the snowflake icon, swap to a different icon, and then play the second half of the animation in the different icon. This is the code I have inside the icon:

`<Button variant="contained" style={{  borderRadius: 50, transition: 'all 0.3s ease', }} onClick={() => acChange(acMode)} color={ acMode === 1 ? "cool" : acMode === 2 ? "heat" : acMode === 3 ? "fan" : "autoMode" } > <FontAwesomeIcon  icon={acMode === 1 ? faSnowflake : acMode === 2 ? faFire : acMode === 3 ? faFan : faSnowflake}  size="lg" shake style={{ transition: 'all 0.3s ease', }}/> </Button>`

Right now the fade just plays continuously. Also even though I have the transition styling here, it still doesn't do the transition at all.The button module is a mui button component, but even if I place the icon outside of the button component it still doesn't do any transition.

Comment: Why does it look so unformatted how do you format this properly